# Entity Framework running SQL query with desired output

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

When using Linq I am not able to make use of SQL Full-Text Search capability so I would like to use SqlQuery method on DbSet which allows me to write a raw SQL query.

Let consider following code:

```
IQueryable<Message> query = DBContext.Set<Message>();
PagedList<Message> messages = query.Where(x => x.Content.Contains("magic"))
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .ToPagedList<Message>(50, 2);
```

if I would like to run following SqlQuery query:

```
DBContext.Set<Message>().SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE CONTAINS("Content", 'magic')");
```

SqlQuery method returns `IEnumerable<Message>` and I would like to have `PagedList<Message>` object returned. What would be the optimal(good) way to achieve it? Notice that I would like my database to execute SQL query and not to filter in memory.

PagedList implementation

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList
{
    public PagedList()
    {
        this.TotalCount = 0;
        this.PageSize = 0;
        this.PageIndex = 0;
        this.TotalPages = 0;
        this.CurrentPage = 0;
    }

    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        this.TotalCount = source.Count();
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);
        this.CurrentPage = Math.Max(1, pageIndex);
        this.AddRange(source.Skip((this.CurrentPage - 1)  * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }

    public PagedList(List<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
    {
        this.TotalCount = source.Count();
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = index;
        this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);
        this.CurrentPage = Math.Max(1, index);
        this.AddRange(source.Skip(index * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
    }

    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

Paged list extension method:

```
public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int pageIndex, int pageSize) where T : class
{
      return new PagedList<T>(query, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply do

```
DBContext.Set<Message>().SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE CONTAINS("Content", 'magic')")
.AsQueryable()
.ToPagedList<Message>(50, 2);
```

Comment: That was crossing my mind. Problem is that all objects matching the original query will have to be loaded into memory from the database.